# Kali linux 2016 brightness control not working after upgrade

Tags: linux, kali-linux, intel-graphics, brightness

I have recently installed kali linux 2016. Brightness control was working correctly but when i updated  and upgrade the system brightness control seems unable to work. Brightness now remains at high i am unable to lower it down.
I have tried many solutions like one with shows error.

```
root@kali:~# xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.7
warning: output LVDS1 not found; ignoring
xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.
```

also in Settings->Details..   in graphics part it shows none.
my laptop is lenovo G5080 i5 5th gen

Comment: We only support official version s

Comment: Kali is a testing distribution. Use any stable distro if you don't wanna testing and bugreporting.

Comment: so what should i do now ? @IporSircer

Comment: Choose:
a) report the bug to kali developers
b) fix the bug yourself then send the solution to kali developers
c) use a stable non-rolling distro

Comment: okay i'll do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from kali linux official issue [page](https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=3547) :

> Those issues are due to GNOME being in transition between GNOME 3.20 and GNOME 3.21 in Debian Testing currently. We have to wait until updated mutter/gnome-shell enter Debian Testing (and thus Kali Rolling).

you can use `xbacklight` to change brightness from the command line, to install it open your terminal and type :

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

then type `xbacklight -set 30` to change your brightness to 30% for example.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION for those who `xbacklight` does not work for

**WARNING:** If you set these settings to low you will not be able to see your screen.

I fixed this by going to the intel backlight directory. Go here to determine your current brightness; THIS IS IMPORTANT 
because you need to know how many digits are involved
Mine was `700000`

`/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`

Change the following with `nano` or `gedit` to a value between `100000` and `700000` for different levels

`/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Here's my graphics hardware as an example:

```
# lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Answer (score 0):

just goto computer/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight(open which ever you have there--i am using intel_backlight)
there you will see baclight file. just open it. you will see value , there keep what % level of brightness and save it. immediately you will see the results. i am using  intel_backlight.